# jQuery not working in Chrome but working on jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

OK I'm trying a simple `anchor` tag javascript that will trigger the submit instead of input-submit

here's my JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('1');
    $( "#vote-poll" ).click(function() {
        alert('2');
        $( "#form-vote" ).submit();
    });

    $( "#form-vote" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('3');

    });
});
```

Just assume every element is correct because I tried it in Firefox and it's working fine.
I tried it in Chrome, it only alerts the "1".
I tried it in Chrome on jsFiddle and it worked..

I really don't know whats wrong in this.

Comment: whether the elements in question are created dynamically after the page is loaded

Comment: change `alert('1');` to `alert('1: ' + $( "#vote-poll" ).length);` and see what is alerted

Comment: @Arun, it returns 0, why is that?

Comment: looks like your element is created after the script is executed... use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Comment: ok thanks Arun, but why is this happening in Chrome only?

Comment: tried the on(click, still the same

Comment: not sure... if you can share more context about how those elements are created we can have a better look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61649/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-roi).

Comment: its working now.. thanks Arun you can add those to answer so I can vote it